# A phenomenon in which bubble points on the boundary line are cut off

Tags: angular, chart.js

[image]

How can I print out the bubbles on the border so that they don't get cut off?

https://stackblitz.com/github/santam85/ng2-charts-bubble-template?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,package-lock.json&preset=node

I used  "chart.js": "^4.3.3",
I don't want to increase the value of min, max.

I hope it will be printed out as shown in the picture below.
[image]

it is sample on Chart.js homepage.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/bubble.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the [clip property](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bubble.html#general) to your datasets to fix this issue.

```js
public bubbleChartDatasets: ChartConfiguration<'bubble'>['data']['datasets'] = [
    {
      clip:20,
      data: [
        { x: 10, y: 10, r: 10 },
        { x: 15, y: 0, r: 35 },
        { x: 26, y: 12, r: 23 },
        { x: 7, y: 8, r: 8 },
      ],
      label: 'Series A',
    },
  ];
```